# Has anyone connected a 3G dongle to Raspberry pi 3 with windows IoT Core?

Tags: driver, windows-10-universal, raspberry-pi3, dongle, windows-iot-core-10

I need to connect a 3G Dongle to my Raspberry Pi running windows IoT Core. I currently have a Vodafone K5160 Dongle but I don't seem to have the required drivers for WindowsIot Core. I read that you need Universal driver for this but it is not practical to build one for each dongle and neither am I familair with driver development. Is there any workaround for this ? Or has anyone connected another dongle/ has necessary drivers?
I deperately need one please.:)
Thank you guys!

Comment: K5160 is not officially supported by microsoft yet, K515- is. https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/docs/hardwarecompatlist. However, you may still try the approach in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35617679/usb-mobile-broadband-modem-on-windows-10-iot.

Comment: @Jackie Thankyou! I had tried this approach - [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35617679/usb-mobile-broadband-modem-on-windows-10-iot) earlier but I got stuck. It said the profile was not created with this command 'netsh mbn add profile interface="Cellular" name="profile.xml" ' .

Comment: @Jonathan Hiben Can you maybe help?

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it working using a K5160 Vodafone 3G Dongle. I used partly the approach in [USB Mobile Broadband Modem on Windows 10 IoT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35617679/usb-mobile-broadband-modem-on-windows-10-iot) with a few modifications.

Comment: Could you please share how you were able to make it work?

Comment: @njoshy how do you solve that problem? I'm unable to connect dongle3G to my raspi3 with iot core. Can you help me, please?

Comment: @EmanueleLeoni What is the problem currently? The link given above solved my issues.

Comment: @njoshy thanks for your reply. Finally I solved my problem, it was an incorrect profile