# Windows 10 IOT 4G Tethering says "DisabledByOperator" but works on Windows 10 Desktop

Tags: netsh, lte, tethering, windows-iot-core-10

I'm trying to set up tethering on Windows 10 IOT using a Raspberry Pi 3 and a Huawei K5160.

Following instructions here:

[USB Mobile Broadband Modem on Windows 10 IoT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35617679/usb-mobile-broadband-modem-on-windows-10-iot)

and

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/910cbbd6-7656-422a-b09d-8657f7e50251/sad-state-of-cellular-modem-support-on-windows-10-iot-core?forum=WindowsIoT

I've set up the modem and it seems to work fine except for tethering.

The connection doesn't show in the tethering setup page on the web interface and if I run the following:

```
var lteProfile = NetworkInformation.GetConnectionProfiles().FirstOrDefault(p => p.NetworkAdapter.IanaInterfaceType == 243);
var capability = NetworkOperatorTetheringManager.GetTetheringCapabilityFromConnectionProfile(lteProfile);
```

Using the same modem with the same SIM card, on the desktop capability is set to "Enabled", but on IOT it's "DisabledByOperator". I've confirmed with the operator that tethering is enabled.

My only thought it is that this difference is either something to do with the fact that on the desktop the connection profile is somehow created automatically whereas on IOT I had to copy the profile from the desktop... or it's a bug in IOT but I've tried a few different builds with no difference.

I've spent a number of hours trawling through documentation on the profile XML format and netsh mbn but there doesn't seem to be anything there which could affect the tethering state, plus as far as I can tell, DisabledByOperator should be based on a flag from the Operator...

Edit:

For further clarity, I have set the SubscriberID as per the above instructions before copying the XML to my IOT device and the modem connects correctly and obtains an IP address on the IOT device, so the profile must be correct (at least correct enough for standard use!). The only thing which doesn't seem to work is tethering...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure it is a bug in IoT. Even though Huawei/Vodafone K5160 modem is in the [hardware compatibility list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/learn-about-hardware/hardwarecompatlist), it is not Microsoft Verified. I think maybe you did not set a correct value for subscriber ID. You can refer to following document:
http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/E/7/7E7662CF-CBEA-470B-A97E-CE7CE0D98DC2/MB_CustGuide.docx。

This document explains how to create an mobile broadband connection with commandline, and get the subscriberID.

```
for /f "tokens=1,2* delims=: " %%i in ('netsh mbn show ready *') do (
  if "%%i"=="Subscriber" SET SUB_ID=%%k
)
```

Above command will get the subscriber ID of the available device.

Hope that is helpful for you.

Comment: I already set the SubscriberID as described above and in the other instructions that I linked before copying the profile XML across. It's my understanding that if this is set incorrectly the modem won't connect and get an IP address, but it does. The only bit which doesn't work is tethering. I'll update the original question to be a bit more specific

Comment: @VaticanUK, can the device ping a external ipaddress? What did you mean about tethering, did it mean using the Huawei K5160 as a access point/hot spot for other device?

Comment: @michael-xu-msft yes the interface comes up fine and works. Tethering is the capability determined by the call to "NetworkOperatorTetheringManager.GetTetheringCapabilityFromConnectionProfile", which is what operators call using a mobile interface as a hotspot

Comment: I think you need to make the mobile boardband modem for tethering manually. You can try via command `netsh mbn set`. Sorry that for i have no mobile boardband modem to test this issue.

Comment: I don't think that's correct. There is no option under "netsh mbn set" relating to tethering, plus it's not required on desktop win 10...

Comment: @VaticanUK, have you tried to start tethering via following this document(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/connect-your-device/internetconnectionsharing)?This document describes how internet connection sharing (ICS) can be enabled on Windows IoT Core. You can refer to the ICS code sample `var result = await tetheringManager.StartTetheringAsync(); `.

Comment: @michael-xu-msft Yes. StartTetheringAsync doesn't work on the IoT device but does on desktop (though it does if I try to share an Ethernet connection rather than the 4g connection). That's what led me to the "GetTetheringCapabilityFromConnectionProfile" method which returns different results on desktop to IoT and explains why it works on one but not the other. Given the different results from "GetTetheringCapabilityFromConnectionProfile" which explain why "StartTetheringAsync" doesn't work, I thought I'd keep the question simple...

Comment: @VaticanUK Based on the error message **DisabledByOperator**, it seems that the tethering was disabled. Since you have mentioned that you already confirm with the operater, I also suggest that double check whether the issue is relative to SIM card by **testing the tethering on Windows 10 IoT core using the same SIM card which works well for Windows 10 desktop**.

Comment: @fei-xue that's exactly what I originally did... Quote from the question "Using the same modem with the same SIM card, on the desktop capability is set to "Enabled", but on IOT it's "DisabledByOperator". I've confirmed with the operator that tethering is enabled"

Comment: @VaticanUK Thanks for the detail info, would you minding also sharing the build os version of Windows 10 IoT you have tested?

Comment: In-addition, [here](https://github.com/ms-iot/iot-utilities/tree/master/MBBConnect) is a helpful tool to help setup configurations for mobile broadband connection in IoT Core

Comment: @VaticanUK In-addition, if it is possible I also suggest that you test it using the device which already verified by Microsoft like Vodafone (Huawei) K5150.

Comment: I've tried builds 17134 and 17661. Unfortunately the K5160 is the only LTE device that I have which works with IoT... I do have another device but it doesn't show up as an LTE device.

Comment: Just to finally report back. I couldn't get the tool to compile, however looking through the source code it would have made a profile XML file practically identical to the one that I had since it just used net commands to get values and then set them in the XML. I gave up on Win 10 IOT as being too immature and moved on to looking at other platforms