# Unable to connect Dongle K5150 to iot core

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, windows-10-iot-core, emnify

I'm trying to connect Dongle K5150 with Emnify SIM to raspberry Pi3 with iot core 17763 version.
I followed these steps:
[USB Mobile Broadband Modem on Windows 10 IoT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35617679/usb-mobile-broadband-modem-on-windows-10-iot)
but at the end I had an error:
Connect Failure: error 0x139f.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution,
the problem was in my "profile.xml".

In detail in two nodes:

```
<HomeProviderName>em</HomeProviderName>
```

and

```
<AccessString>em</AccessString>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may get error 0x139f (ERROR_INVALID_STATE) in the case when the device is roaming but the roaming policy disallows data roaming - error on a connect request sent to wwansvc. You can try to toubleshoot this issue with this article.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/troubleshooting#issue-when-connecting-a-mbm-device-when-roaming

Comment: Hi @Michael Xu - MSFT , I have read this article before, but I didn't understand what I have to add or modify in my profile.xml.
Can you help me?